# How can I declare a c++ class enum outside of the .h file?

Tags: c++, class, enums

I have this massive 200 line class enum (for IC device registers) and would like to move it out of `MyClass.h` and into a new file called `MyClassRegisters.cpp`, purely for organization/stylistic purposes.

How can I do this?

Would the `.cpp` file have something like `enum MyClass::MyEnum { ONE, TWO, THREE, ... }` ?

I can't seem to find an docs or examples on the subject.

Comment: I would think "enum MyEnum {}" - in its own .h file - would be *better* "organization".  Wouldn't it?

Comment: Where is this enum used? If it is only used in a single .cpp file, declare it there and not in the .h file. If its actual definition is used in other .cpp files, they need the definition, so the definition must be available in a .h file.
But you can forward-declare an enum just like you can for a class, but then other files that don't see the definition can only hold variables of the type and not use the enum in other ways.

Comment: You can move it to the cpp file with no issue as long as you don't mention the enum in the header or use it anywhere else in your code.

Comment: What code needs to see the values enumerated by the enum?

Comment: when writing IC drivers it is wise to make an enum to name all the registers - but for this specific IC I am working on it has a register map exceeding 200 registers. I use the "register enum" to basically note things from the data sheet via a comment. 

Ex. `enum Registers { IC_REG = 0xH1, // this reg is for blah blah blah... }

Comment: Strictly speaking, you can "move it out of `MyClass.h` and into a new file called `MyClassRegisters.cpp`" by opening `MyClass.h`, selecting the definition, cutting, opening a new file, pasting, and saving as `MyClassRegisters.cpp`. Why don't you do this? (Yes, this will almost certainly cause compilation errors, but those are **why** you should not do this and have nothing to do with the **how** that you asked about.)

Comment: Food for thought: go to a place in your code where you use, for example, `Registers::IC_REG`. How does the compiler know whether or not `IC_REG` is a valid enumerate at that point in your code?

Comment: is it safe to say that what I am aiming to do is not possible without some serious janking of the code?